# How to direct print to a printer In POS software without showing window print dialog?

Tags: php, pos

I have POS software in Which Receipt is print with 3 to 4 step. this is long method. i want to  Receipt print without showing window print dialog box. direct print to the printer
i am using php CodeIgniter Web Framework.
after showing receipt on print button the function is following

```js
function PrintTicket() {
   $('.modal-body').removeAttr('id');
   window.print();
   $('.modal-body').attr('id', 'modal-body');
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-add hiddenpr" onclick="PrintTicket()"><?=label("print");?></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do in the following way:

```
//For hide dialog box
function PrintTicket() {
   $('.modal-body').modal('hide');
   window.print();   
}

//For show dialog box
function PrintTicket() {
   window.print();   
   $('.modal-body').modal('show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use php for print directly to printer.

you can use [mike42 escpos github](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) plugin.

after download you need to make a connector for your printer.
use [this](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php#using-a-printconnector)

after you can print.
my sample for a shared printer and for a php file that is running by schedule task is:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\CapabilityProfile;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;


$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("smb://computername/printername");
$printer = new Printer($connector);

$printer -> text("hello world");
$printer -> text("\n");
$printer -> text("\n");
$printer -> text("hello again");
$printer -> cut();
$printer -> close();
```